# Cannot find source file: "audioplayers_helpers.h" while building Flutter project on Windows

Tags: flutter, flutter-windows, flutter-audioplayers

I need to play sound in my Flutter app so I used **audioplayers** package. It works well on my Android device, but I'm getting this error when running the project on **Windows**!

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
main.dart:1
CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/audioplayers_windows/windows/CMakeLists.txt:32 (add_library):
  Cannot find source file:

    audioplayers_helpers.h

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .mpp .m .M .mm .ixx .cppm .h
  .hh .h++ .hm .hpp .hxx .in .txx .f .F .for .f77 .f90 .f95 .f03 .hip .ispc


CMake Error at flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/audioplayers_windows/windows/CMakeLists.txt:32 (add_library):
  No SOURCES given to target: audioplayers_windows_plugin


CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
Exception: Unable to generate build files
Exited (sigterm)
```

I'm using the latest version of audioplayers package (v5.1.0).

Thanks in advance.